# How to extract the certificate (so that domain name) from the sniffer with Java?

Tags: java, ssl, networking, certificate, jpcap

I tried to sniff the network data flow and extract the certificates for HTTPS with Java. (In python, the package named [Scapy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scapy-ssl_tls/1.2.2) could achieve this.) My ultimate goal is to dump the packets and find the domain name containing in their certificates (if any).

I have explored a bit but most articles focus on either dumping the packet & printing out simple information (eg. addr, port), or reading the certificate from file and somehow parsing it. I don't find any to combine these two.

I have tried [Jpcap](http://jpcap.gitspot.com/install.html) and to parse the packets (it's not my code, I modified this code from Internet). But I failed to extract the correct certificate from it.

Here is the main code:

```
// implements PacketReceiver
@Override
public void receivePacket(Packet p)
{
    if (p instanceof TCPPacket)
    {
        TCPPacket tcp = (TCPPacket) p;
        // receivePost == 443
        if (tcp.src_port == receivePost || tcp.dst_port == receivePost)
        {
            byte[] bytes = tcp.data;
            // ((int) bytes[0]) == 22 -> Handshake
            // This is the main part I'm not sure. Some packets do go into this if.
            if (bytes != null && bytes.length > 6 && ((int) bytes[0]) == 22)
            {
                StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();

                for (int i = 0, j; i < bytes.length;)
                {
                    for (j = 0; j < 8 && i < bytes.length; j++, i++)
                    {
                        String d = Integer
                                .toHexString((int) (bytes[i] & 0xff));
                        buf.append((d.length() == 1 ? "0" + d : d) + " ");
                        if (bytes[i] < 32 || bytes[i] > 126)
                            bytes[i] = 46;
                    }
                }

                String[] data = buf.toString().split(" ");
                // Parse the length of cert
                // I must be wrong here, the length is extremely large
                int certLength = Integer.parseInt(data[12] + data[13]
                        + data[14], 16);
                // Extract the cert
                StringBuffer certString = new StringBuffer();
                for (int i = 0; i < certLength; i++)
                {
                    certString.append(data[i + 15]);
                }
                // The byte array to store the cert
                byte[] cert = new byte[certLength];

                for (int i = 0; i < certLength; i++)
                {
                    String tempstr = certString.substring(i * 2, i * 2 + 2);
                    cert[i] = uniteBytes(tempstr);
                }

                try
                {
                    CertificateFactory certFactory = CertificateFactory
                            .getInstance("X.509");
                    InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
                    X509Certificate xcert = (X509Certificate) certFactory
                            .generateCertificate(in);
                    System.out.println("DN："
                            + xcert.getSubjectDN().getName());
                } catch (CertificateException e)
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Please help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do all that when the OpenSSL [`s_client`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/apps/s_client.html) command will give you the certificate, free and clear?

Comment: @Andreas  Because I want to get the cert from ongoing connections. And I may not know which connections exist. Do you have any idea whether this OpenSSL tool could achieve this? Thanks!